# posting message from my site to facebook wall

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-c#-sdk

I am trying to post message on facebook wall . i tried with developer.facebok and the settigns in that asking for site to which i have to link .actually am working on local now and site is not published in a server. how can i post to facebook wall from my local mechine.

```
    var body = 'Reading Connect JS documentation'; 
    FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { message: body }, function(response) 
    { 
        if (!response || response.error) 
        { 
            alert('Error occured'); 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            alert('Post ID: ' + response.id); 
        } 
    });
```

Comment: i am using following javascript and am gettign error message

Comment: var body = 'Reading Connect JS documentation';
FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { message: body }, function(response) {
  if (!response || response.error) {
    alert('Error occured');
  } else {
    alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
  }
});

Comment: Which kind of error you get!!! Can you please put it over here...

Comment: yes. same error which u can see inside above script ."error occured"

Comment: curently i am login to facebook with my id and i believe "me" should take my id .

Comment: alerting "error occurred" is the way how to tell this to user, but more information can be found in `response.error`. can you tell us, what's in the error property?

Comment: nop i can see only this error

Comment: is there any js that i have to include for using fb.api asin above script

Comment: Editted your code. In IE8/9, press F12, go to network tab, start trace. Show us what's in request and what's in response. Thank you

Comment: hi am able to post now . but now how can i post to wall without using fb-login button .i.e using html submit button. internally post to wall even am not logged in to facebook

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest alerting the response.error instead of the static string, or set a debugger; point there and look at the value.

Also look at the network traffic and check out the response stream if those don't work.

To post to a wall even after the user left your app (but still left the permissions accepted for publish_stream), then you can just user your app id/secret to post as them.  From https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/

> Enables your app to post content, comments, and likes to a user's
>   stream and to the streams of the user's friends. With this permission,
>   you can publish content to a user's feed at any time, without
>   requiring offline_access. However, please note that Facebook
>   recommends a user-initiated sharing model.